# Pass arguments inside API resource call in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to retrieve records using [Logical grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#logical-grouping) in Laravel.
I am doing this in API Resource.

### What I want?

I want to pass arguments inside API resource function and use that value in where condition. For example: `Address::where(function($q1) use (somevalue)`.

### What I did

I tried with the following code.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'name'   => $this->name,
        'domain' => $this->domain,
        'addresses' => AddressResource::collection(Address::where(function($q1) use ($this->company_id){
                $q1->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
            })
            ->where(function($q2) {
                $q2->where('is_shipping', 1)
                    ->orWhere('is_billing', 1);
            })
            ->get()),
    ];
}
```

But the issue here is that `$this->company_id` cannot be passed. It only accepts static values like `abc` BUT not as above `$this->company_id`.

### Error I got

`syntax error, unexpected token \"->\", expecting \")\"` at line number 27

(Note: `'addresses' => AddressResource::coll......` is line number 27)

How can I achieve this? any lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try removing use ($this->company_id) and check .i think we can access class property directly inside call back

Comment: @JohnLobo I tied it but not working. Returning null only.

Comment: okay.then you can create a variable and assing company id to that so you can pass that using use()

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $company_id = $this->company_id;
    return [
        'name'   => $this->name,
        'domain' => $this->domain,
        'addresses' => AddressResource::collection(Address::where(function($q1) use ($company_id){
            $q1->where('company_id', $company_id);
        })
            ->where(function($q2) {
                $q2->where('is_shipping', 1)
                    ->orWhere('is_billing', 1);
            })
            ->get()),
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and was doing a mistake. I need to get `$this->id` but not `$this->company_id` because I am inside CompanyResource.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass directly. take a Var abc and store your value $abc = $this->company_id; then pass to the closure fucntion. I Hope this will work